# Trigger SharePoint workflow after an SSIS import.

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

For some reason I am not able to trigger a SharePoint List workflow after adding a new item to the SharePoint list. I am using SSIS to add the items to the list.

Things I tried: 
1. Add the item manually in the list -- sends the email 
2. Run SSIS, verify that the item was added to the list, waited a couple minutes -- no email.

Is this even possible? Alerts seem work fine, but I would like to customize the email.

Comment: are all the fields being populated? I wonder if it's holding off the workflow until some fields are. SharePoint will check out the item to user in draft form until all required fields are filled in...

Comment: Not all of the fields are populated but if I start the workflow manually against the item it does send the email.

Comment: How exactly are you importing data into sharepoint using ssis? Is this a database transaction?

Comment: Using SSIS I get the data from a sharepoint list (List1) and put it on Sharepoint list (list2). Both lists are under the same site and they have the same exact structure. The only exception is that list2 has no items and has a SharePoint workflow that just send an email when an item is added or modified.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that the green *New* tag isn't on the items. This is an indicator that the event receiver isn't getting fired "ItemAdded". What does the modified date say? Is older data retaining that value?

Comment: Also is the item being created by the system account? Last I remember that won't trigger a workflow to start.

Comment: Modified date and Created date are set to today (time of import) and the "new" item green message is displayed.

Comment: Wait. I think you got it. I am connecting to the data using system account. Let me change that.

Comment: It didn't work. However, I created a new list with just a couple columns made the mapping and it worked. It was thank to you that this happened. Thank you so much if you provide an answer I will give you the credit.